# Using XMPP developing a client which acts a mediator in two users

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

I am working on a requirement in which user will ask query and that query will be routed to group of users. Group of users can directly communicate with seeker. All using XMPP python client and XMPP server(ejabberd)

Detailed scenario:

1. User1@example.com asks a query and it is destined to  answers@example.com
2. answers@example.com select a list of users(g1) from database and forwards query to them.
3. Each member of g1 replies individually to User1@example.com even though message is sent from answers@example.com

Step 1 is trivial XMPP and done already

Step 2 can be taken care of

Step 3 I am doubtful if it can be done. What features of XMPP I need to focus on. Please enlighten.

PS: I am writing custom clients using xmppp.py

Answer (score 0):

I don't think step 3 can quite be done with plain XMPP, but, if your XMPP server is your own, and it supports plugins, one possible workaround would be to write a plugin that "fakes" this interaction by making answers@example.com pretend to be User1@example.com from the point of view of the other users when making the question.

Another possibility would be to use the multi-user-chat, but that won't quite give the result you want, either.